# Download Multiple Images from URL List (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, imagedownload

I am trying to download many images from a list of URLs. 
When I use this code on just one image, it works fine.

```
img = Image.open(requests.get(url_dict[key], stream = True).raw)
        img.save(f'images/{file_name}.jpg')
```

When I run it through the for loop below, it downloads a bunch of empty files with no extension.
Why?
How do I fix this?

```
for key in url_dict:
    file_name = key.replace(' ', '_')
    img = Image.open(requests.get(url_dict[key], stream = True).raw)
    img.save(f'images/{file_name}.jpg')
```

I am expecting to get a folder full of images that actually contain data.

Comment: can you add an example of your url_dict?
all images are jpg?

Comment: They are all jpg, yes. It works when I try any random 1 from the dict, but when I loop it, it just downloads empty files.

Comment: If possible could you provide the list of urls  you are trying ? or similar ones that can reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the format of the pillow image to create the file.

I've tried this code with different URLs and worked ok for me.

```
import requests
from PIL import Image

url_dict = {"river":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/Escudo_del_C_A_River_Plate.svg/1200px-Escudo_del_C_A_River_Plate.svg.png","river1":"https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/LS7e70lkgIyJHxBWKr1YY5BRytD7Aw2th-dk8K66kU-c-fkr5e2Yo3Eh2RK9vFanYh8"}

for key in url_dict:
    file_name = key.replace(' ', '_')
    img = Image.open(requests.get(url_dict[key], stream = True).raw)
    img.save(f'images/{file_name}.{img.format.lower()}')
```

Comment: Using this code still exports a bunch of empty files with no extension for me.

Comment: even with the example url_dict in the answer?

Comment: No, sorry overlooked that. I just tried with your dict and it works.
Here is an example of the urls in my dict. Sorry cant share them all.

https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0704/3268/6367/products/preview_d97e853f-ab59-4c48-a4ef-ed4d9c16cdb0.jpg?v=1676777680

Comment: It's working for me. Make sure the URLs in your dict contains `https://....`and the `images` folder exists

Comment: These example urls dont seem to be working. They do have https and .jpg. The images folder exists.

https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0704/3268/6367/products/preview_dece2ca5-c06c-45f7-b655-c6b7f87853bf.jpg
https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0704/3268/6367/products/preview_31c4e954-1b97-480b-85f8-7f6c1d2a56c2.jpg

Comment: Those urls are working ok for me. As .jpg and .pgn too. 
I can't replicate your error. My PIL version is '9.4.0' and my requests version is '2.28.2'. What are you using as keys for your dict? I guess the error could be there

Comment: Ughh THANK YOU! You solved it for me. It was my keys. I completely overlooked that all the keys had a colon in them which was causing the issue. Dumb mistake. Thanks so much Pedro! Super helpful!